# Laravel 5.2 Multiple forms on Register Page

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm working on a project with Laravel 5.2.* and I'm using the default auth controllers and views. My end goal is to have 2 forms on 1 page for register. When the user registers they can either sign up as a provider or a normal user. I created a new column in the 'users' database called 'provider'.

I'm also using LaravelCollective HTML/Forms to generate the forms.

I created two forms in the view:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Family Form</h2>
            {!! Form::open() !!}

            {{ Form::label('name', "Name:") }}
            {{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::hidden('provider', false) }}

            {{ Form::label('email', "Email:") }}
            {{ Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::label('password', "Password:") }}
            {{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', "Confirm Password:") }}
            {{ Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::submit('Register', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block form-spacing-top']) }}

            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Provider Form</h2>
            {!! Form::open() !!}

            {{ Form::label('name', "Name:") }}
            {{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::hidden('provider', true) }}

            {{ Form::label('email', "Email:") }}
            {{ Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::label('password', "Password:") }}
            {{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', "Confirm Password:") }}
            {{ Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::submit('Register', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block form-spacing-top']) }}

            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
```

and then in the Auth\AuthController I edited the 'create' function to add the 'provider' boolean:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'provider' => $data['provider'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

}
```

Now my issue is, no matter what form I fill out it ALWAYS saves as FALSE or '0' in the database under 'provider'

Here is the HTML output for the forms:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Family Form</h2>
            <form method="POST" action="//localhost:3000/auth/register" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Rli5AmRKkov64hPt6AEfr7yOLwA5EwUmozVePgQL">

            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" id="name">

            <input name="provider" type="hidden" value="">

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" id="email">

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" value="" id="password">

            <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" type="password" value="" id="password_confirmation">

            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block form-spacing-top" type="submit" value="Register">

            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Provider Form</h2>
            <form method="POST" action="//localhost:3000/auth/register" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Rli5AmRKkov64hPt6AEfr7yOLwA5EwUmozVePgQL">

            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" id="name">

            <input name="provider" type="hidden" value="1">

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" id="email">

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" value="" id="password">

            <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" type="password" value="" id="password_confirmation">

            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block form-spacing-top" type="submit" value="Register">

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If there is no way to support two forms on the same registration page, is there a way to create 2 separate register pages, one for "Family" and one for "Provider" while still using the default AUTH system? I tried earlier however whenever there was a validation issue it would always redirect to /auth/register

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What is the data type of provider field in your db?

Comment: As far as I can see, the fields for both forms are the same(?). Why would you want them to be two forms then in the first place, why not simply use radio buttons to let the user choose in _one single form_ what type of account they want to register?

Comment: @TheAlpha is a boolean

Comment: @CBroe I'm going to add 5 more fields for the provider to enter. I'm just trying to get the boolean working first :p

Comment: How do you determine which form to show ?

Comment: @TheAlpha I'm going to use javascript to only show 1 form at a time, and depending which link they select from the homepage it will show that form.

Honestly the more I think about it, the better it may be to have 2 different pages.

Comment: I disagree, having _one_ form has more benefits here IMHO. I’d use radio buttons to choose the registration type - and when it is provider, use JS to show the extra form fields that have been hidden/disabled so far. It might be an UX issue as well; maybe the user is not sure which type they want when the start filling out the form - oops, now I switched and have to type the same info again in a different form ...? (Sure, that could be handled via scripting as well - but why complicate something to such a degree, that could be rather simple?

Comment: @CBroe True, thanks a ton for your reply! I really appreciate it and you've helped out a ton! I'll use your suggestion with the radio button, you're awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I forgot to add 'provider' to $fillable in the User model..

I've solved my own issue, however if there is a better way to go about doing this, I'd love to learn!

App\User.php:

```
protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'provider', 'email', 'password' ];
```